# Neo4 web interface remains empty white page after upgrading to 4.0.3

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 4.0.3 web interface remains empty in Safari on my MacBook Air running Mac OX 10.14.6.
Version 4.0.0 was working well, I configured 4.0.3 the same way I configured v4.0.0.
I wanted to upgrade to 4.0.3 as 4.0.0 sometimes fail displaying node labels, relationships types and properties in the left panel.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line should be uncommented in the config file.

```
dbms.default_advertised_address=localhost
```